# Sandbox account payment status is unclaimed and not working ony my app

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a shop program and it's not working anymore, it shows like this

[image]

I can't used my app anymore, help me please. and when I open on the sandbox account it shows **unclaimed** not **completed**.

MAX_NUMBER_OF_PAYMENT_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED